# Cannot set property 'paginator' of undefined - Unit Testing

Tags: angular, angular-material, karma-jasmine

I'm doing a unit testing on one of my component in Angular. The test scenario is to check if a div element with a class `.div-container` is exists in the page.
So basically, a variable in my component.ts dictates whether the said div is visible or not using `*ngIf`.

Please see my codes below what I have so far.

**HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="isAdmin">
    <div class='div-container'>
       <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortActive="DisplayName"
        matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Firstname">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>First Name</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            {{row.Firstname}}
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="Lastname">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Last Name</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.Lastname}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="Gender">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Gender</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.Gender}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      </table>
      <mat-paginator [length]="resultsLength" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 50, 100]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
    </div>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
    if (ms !== undefined) {
      this.sort = ms;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }
  }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    if (mp !== undefined) {
      this.paginator = mp;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.names$ = this.dataService.names$
      .pipe(
        tap(names => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          this.resultsLength = names.value.length;

          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(names.value);
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      )
  }
}
```

**SPEC**

```
describe('SampleComponent', () => {
  let component: SampleComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SampleComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [SharedModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        MatSortModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule],
      declarations: [SampleComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SampleComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    paginator = component.matPaginator;
    sort = component.matSort;

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it(`should hide the div container if 'isAdmin' is false`, () => {
    component.isAdmin = false;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.div-container'))).toBeNull();
  });

  it(`should show the div container if 'isAdmin' is true`, () => {
    component.isAdmin = true;

    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.div-container'))).toBeTruthy();
  });
);
```

Unfortunately, I cannot make this test to pass due to this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'paginator' of undefined.
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to properly address this error.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You try to set your `dataSource` paginator even before the `dataSource` was generated with `new`. Try to check if your `dataSource` is present before setting the paginator.

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    if (mp !== undefined && this.dataSource) {  // <-- should fix your problem
      this.paginator = mp;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
it('should handle pagination correctly', () => {
      const mockPaginator: MatPaginator = {
        length: 40,
        pageSize: 10,
        pageIndex: 0,
        pageSizeOptions: [10, 15, 20],
        hasPreviousPage: () => component.paginator.pageIndex > 0,
        hasNextPage: () =>
          component.paginator.pageIndex < Math.ceil(component.paginator.length /                                     component.paginator.pageSize),
      } as MatPaginator;
      component.paginator = mockPaginator;
      component.paginator.pageIndex = 1;
      while (component.paginator.hasNextPage()) {
        component.paginator.pageIndex++;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      }
      expect(component.paginator.pageIndex).toEqual(4);
    }); 
   you can moch MatPaginator and test the behaviour
```

it('should handle pagination correctly', () => {
const mockPaginator: MatPaginator = {
length: 40,
pageSize: 10,
pageIndex: 0,
pageSizeOptions: [10, 15, 20],
hasPreviousPage: () => component.paginator.pageIndex > 0,
hasNextPage: () =>
component.paginator.pageIndex < Math.ceil(component.paginator.length /                                     component.paginator.pageSize),
} as MatPaginator;
component.paginator = mockPaginator;
component.paginator.pageIndex = 1;
while (component.paginator.hasNextPage()) {
component.paginator.pageIndex++;
fixture.detectChanges();
}
expect(component.paginator.pageIndex).toEqual(4);
});
you can moch MatPaginator and test the behaviour